# Record video of the screen using an App on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, video

I want to build an App that allows me to record what i am doing on my iphone.. like a mirror broadcast but without using external Apps or connect it to a mac.

is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u are talking about onscreen-recording then,

Check this [link](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673), u will get a valid program.

What this does is it saves the contents of a UIView to a UIImage. The author suggests you can save a video of the app in use by passing the frames through AVCaptureSession.

I believe it hasn't been tested with an OpenGL subview, but assuming that it works you might be able to modify it slightly to include audio and then you'd be set.

Refer the comments section in the link to t mix audio & video and save it as a quicktime movie.

Also,

Another useful project for this is RecordMyScreen, found [here](https://github.com/coolstar/RecordMyScreen)

Answer (score 0):

```
Search in mac .. Quick Time Player..
```

[image]

> Then Open it. and Right CLick and you will find NEw Screen Recording
>   Option

[image]

> And You Have to follow below Step.

[image]

[image]

[image]

> And Finally You have Video